# Парсинг сложного JSON в android с использованием библиотеки GSON

Tags: java, android, gson

```
{
  "company": {
    "name": "XXX",
    "age": "15",
    "competences": [
      "Android",
      "IOS",
      ".NET",
      "PHP",
      "Smart-TV"
    ],
    "employees": [
      {
        "name": "John",
        "phone_number": "769453",
        "skills": [
          "Java",
          "Android"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Diego",
        "phone_number": "987924",
        "skills": [
          "Java",
          "Smart-TV"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Alfred",
        "phone_number": "452533",
        "skills": [
          "Objective-C",
          "Android",
          "Photoshop"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "John",
        "phone_number": "212456",
        "skills": [
          "Java",
          "Phython"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Mat",
        "phone_number": "778975",
        "skills": [
          "Android",
          "MovieMaker"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Bob",
        "phone_number": "456468",
        "skills": [
          "Groovy",
          "Kotlin"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Marty",
        "phone_number": "321789",
        "skills": [
          "Android",
          "PHP",
          "C#"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Имеется JSON, нужно получить список работников (`employee`) со всеми полями.  Подскажите, пожалуйста, как всё организовать.

Comment: вы наверное не видели сложных (плохо структурированных ) Json. То что у вас в примере легко (идеально) парсится 1 Single запросом, и конвертируется через GoogleGSON. Поэтому вопрос звучит как распарсить такой JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваши **POJO**:

```
class MyResponse {
    private Company company;

    public MyResponse(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    // getters & setters
}

class Company {
    private String name, age;
    private List<String> competences;
    private List<Employee> employees;

    public Company(String name, String age, List<String> competences, List<Employee> employees) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.competences = competences;
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    // getters & setters
}

class Employee {
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("phone_number")
    private String phone;
    private List<String> skills;

    public Employee(String name, String phone, List<String> skills) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.skills = skills;
    }

    // getters & setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
                ", skills=" + skills +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Десериализация:

```
String json = "ваша строчка";

Gson gson = new Gson();
MyResponse response = gson.fromJson(json, MyResponse.class);

System.out.println(response.getCompany().getEmployees());
```

Вывод в консоль (на примере строки, приведённой в вопросе):

> [Employee{name='John', phone='769453', skills=[Java, Android]},
>   Employee{name='Diego', phone='987924', skills=[Java, Smart-TV]},
>   Employee{name='Alfred', phone='452533', skills=[Objective-C, Android,
>   Photoshop]}, Employee{name='John', phone='212456', skills=[Java,
>   Phython]}, Employee{name='Mat', phone='778975', skills=[Android,
>   MovieMaker]}, Employee{name='Bob', phone='456468', skills=[Groovy,
>   Kotlin]}, Employee{name='Marty', phone='321789', skills=[Android, PHP,
>   C#]}]

Пример обработки:

```
response.getCompany().getEmployees().stream()
            .filter(employee -> employee.getSkills().contains("Kotlin"))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Ищем всех работников, которые знают котлин. Вывод в консоль:

> Employee{name='Bob', phone='456468', skills=[Groovy, Kotlin]}

Comment: Спасибо большое, был близок к ответу, но никак не получалось всё сделать. Благодаря Вам могу двигаться дальше, спасибо ещё раз.